# "Initialization failed" while deploying GAE application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, primefaces

While deploying a GAE application, I get errors like:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:211)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:171)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:392)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:162)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

What would be the reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has probably been caused by your servlet having failed its `init` method. There should be another stacktrace before this one with more details.